# useEffect is not triggered

Tags: reactjs

This is my `useProjects` custom hook:

```
    export const useProjects = () => {
      const [projects, setProjects] = useState([]);

      useEffect(() => {
        firebase
          .firestore()
          .collection("projects")
          .where("userId", "==", "cMFAHqzXw9mQRar9eln7")
          .orderBy("projectId")
          .get()
          .then(snapshot => {
            const allProjects = snapshot.docs.map(project => {
              return {
                docId: project.id,
                ...project.data()
              };
            });

            if (JSON.stringify(allProjects) !== JSON.stringify(projects)) {
              setProjects(allProjects);
            }
          });
      }, [projects]);

  return { projects };
};
```

When I use it somewhere, the `useEffect` part is not triggered. What am I doing wrong ? Using it like this:

```
const { projects, setProjects } = useProjects();
```

This returns empty array. I've putted `console.log` in the `useEffect` but it wasn't triggered.

Comment: Can you share the entire `useProjects` customHook

Comment: Missed the last 2 lines. My bad :). Is this the whole hook now? I am sorry but I am new in React and learning this from tutorial video.

Comment: Does your `useffect` fire after initial render?

Comment: No, it does not.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with how you used your hook.

In your useProject, you are returning a json with `projects` inside,
but when you use it you extract it again from the return value, so it will be empty.
You did extraction again with...

```
const { projects, setProjects } = useProjects();
```

so both `projects`, and `setProjects` will be undefined,

change your return to

```
return {projects, setProjects}
```

or juz simply change it to

```
const projects = useProjects();
```

then console your `projects`, there should be something inside.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Try to put a console log on top of your useEffect, another on your useProjects in your main component, and another inside useEffect on top of firebase. See which one did u missed. It is really weird.

Comment: Instead of adding a usehook component try juz copy paste the whole use hook to your main component. See if it run at all